# Removing Specific Characters from txt in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5

I was trying to create a program that would remove * or ! from lines if they started with said characters. Therefore, something like:

```
*81
!81
```

Would change to be:

```
81
81
```

This is the code I'm using as of now:

```
input("Hello")
with open("Test.txt",'r') as c:
    lines = c.readlines()
    c.close()
with open("Test.txt",'w') as c:
    c.truncate()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("!") or line.startswith("*") == False:
            c.write(line)
        if line.startswith("!") or line.startswith("*") == True:
            new_line = line.translate({ord(c): None for c in '* !'})
            print(new_line)
            c.write(new_line)

    c.close()
```

However, only the stars will be removed, what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your boolean conditions aren't correct, you need the test on all conditions and use `and` in that first `if`

```
if line.startswith("!") == False and line.startswith("*") == False:
    ...
```

or better yet, use `not`

```
if not (line.startswith("!") or line.startswith("*")):
    ...
```

And even better still, extract the token you are interested in and check it against an exclusion list

```
with open("Test.txt",'r') as c:
    lines = c.readlines()

with open("Test.txt",'w') as c:
    for line in lines:
        if line[0] in "*!":
            line = line[1:]
        c.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that uses a regular expression substitution:

```
import re

with open("Test.txt",'r+') as c:
        inp = c.read()
        out = re.sub(r'^([\*!])(.*)', r'\2', inp, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        c.seek(0)
        c.write(out)
        c.truncate()
```

Note, the regular expression above will replace only the leading '*' or '!'. Thus, lines that start with any combination of the characters like

```
*!80
!*80
**80
```

would be replaced by

```
!80
*80
*80
```

To replace all leading '*' and '!' on lines that start with the characters, change pattern to

```
'^([\*!]+)(.*)'
```